# docker compose cli to kubectl

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kubectl

My project which need to use the python subprocess module to operate compose yaml file, such as `docker-compose up/start/stop/restart/down`, need to transfer from compose to k8s now

So how does my compose cli correspond to the kubectl cli? For example, `docker-compose up` seems to correspond to `kubectl create/apply`, how to find corresponding commands in kubectl for `docker-compose down,stop,start and restart` commands

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it?

Comment: I would recommend directly using the [Kubernetes API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) over scripting `kubectl`.  Kubernetes and Compose have different abstractions in a couple of places and there aren't necessarily 1:1 mappings between one and the other.

Comment: In comparison, it seems that only `compose up` corresponds to `kubectl apply/create` and `compose down` corresponds to `kubectl delete`. Is there any similar corresponding command I neglected?

Comment: What are the advantages of the Kubernetes API over python subprocess?
I find it easier to use subprocess, since I also need to first convert compose yaml to k8s yml using kompose, subprocess in python should be able to perform `kompose convert`

Comment: An external `kubectl` is an undocumented dependency, and if you're trying to handle things like `kubectl get` output, you're either at the mercy of the tabular format possibly changing between releases, or you're parsing JSON output which an SDK would do for you.

Comment: I tried to find the command to replace `kubectl apply-f export` in `Kubernetes API`. Export is a directory, which contains a series of yaml files of `kompose convert -o export`, but I did not find the relevant replaceable `kubectl` API, whether `Kubernetes API` is not completely complete

Answer (score 1):

It works a bit different way in k8s. Check how [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) works.

Comment: The deployment pause and resume do not have the same operation meaning as the pause in compose. Does this mean that the pause in compose cannot be found in kubectl?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to stop/resume in k8s as you do it in docker-compose.

Comment: At present, I find only `compose up` corresponds to `kubectl apply/create` and `compose down` corresponds to `kubectl delete`. Is there any similar command that I ignored that can correspond to each other?